# Сборка Linux хорошо работающая с двумя мониторами

Tags: kde, linux, linux-mint, gnome, ubuntu

Mint, Ubuntu - постоянно проблемы. Бэкграунд сползает, только половина экрана отрисовывается иногда, текущее состояние и разрешения мониторов никогда не сохраняются - при перезагрузке постоянно приходится выставлять руками, flash-плеер, открытый во весь экран на одном мониторе, сворачивается при клике на другом мониторе.

Посоветуйте хоть что-нибудь... Хоть мануалы по лечению этих проблем, хотя бы по лечению последней - она самая критичная...

Comment: @eprivalov1
Как только проверю - так сразу :)

Comment: Лечить не пробовал, потому как на SuSE и OpenSuSE их никогда не было :)

Comment: У Вас случаем не две видеокарты (встроенная и дополнительная) для разных мониторов используются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я тоже советую ubuntu 10 (на работе игровой комп 2 моника) работает норм, нареканий нет)

Comment: Gnome или KDE? (:

Comment: гном 10.04

Comment: Спасибо, проверю все сборки, плюсую (:

Comment: Проверил, проблема с флешем осталась...

Comment: Но зато при зажатом Ctrl и скролле, флеш объект увеличивается вместе со страницей и текстом в отличие от винды. Решил проблему увеличением, плюс написал небольшое расширение для хрома (что-то типа "* {color: black; background-color: black;"}. Теперь всё затемняется, флеш остаётся увеличенным и всё хорошо :)

Answer (score 4):

Linux Kubuntu 10.10, а также Ubuntu 10.10 и выше работает нормально, таких проблем которые Вы описываете замечено не было!

Comment: Большое спасибо. Поставил качаться, завтра буду эксперементировать :)
Вы проверяли только на 10.10, или точно знаете что версии выше таких багов не имеют?

Comment: Проверял на 10.10, 11.04 и 11.10, думаю что надругих версиях (выше) все тоже замечательно работает!

Comment: Kubuntu - проверил. Хорошо работает с мониторами, но проблема с флешем всё равно есть :(

Answer (score 2):

Пользуюсь Fedora - два монитора работают нормально. Да, при самом старте (несколько секунд после старта гнома) картинка фона немного смещена, но она сама нормализируется.
Насколько мне известно (одно время очень много копал на эту тему) - в федоре есть проблема с двумя мониторами, если используется две видеокарты. На других дистрибутивах тоже есть, но немножко меньше. Если же используется одна видеокарта с двумя выходами - работает все достаточно хорошо.

А вот флешплеер - он не работает нормально нигде. На маковой машине (тоже с двумя мониторами) если развернуть в весь экран на другом мониторе, то пропадает док на основном. Как только выходишь с fullscreen - док появляется.

На моем компьютере флеш плеер иногда разворачивается на пол экрана (то есть такое ощущение, что он пытается разместить картинку между экранами, но половину не рисует). И вряд ли это сильно зависит от дистрибутива. Если флешплеер - это просмотр ютуба, то переключите в режим html5 - у меня этот плеер работает заметно лучше, чем флеш плеер, хотя глюки есть. Но точно работает адекватно в полноэкранном режиме (в гуглхроме).

Comment: Нет, это не глюки флеш-плеера. Даже в винде только в хроме всё работает отлично - в других также сворачивается. Так что тут скорее всего зависит от сборки браузера. В ubuntu было всё хорошо, но потом хром выкатили апдейт - и всё поломалось. На винде вроде как починили, а вот на *unix сборки так и не доделали наверное. И ещё - это не просмотр ютуба - фильмы смотрю :)

Comment: Но спасибо за хороший ответ :)

Comment: а в курсе, что в хроме может использоваться как встроенный флешплеер, так и "наружный". Но это дело можно переключать. в хроме нужно открыть "chrome://plugins/" и выбрать нужный (в некоторых случаях рекомендуется даже выключить один из них - моему соседу помогло, перестало глючить).

Comment: Не знал, спасибо, покопаюсь :)

Comment: Обе версии флеша и на гноме и кедах всё равно сворачивают фуллскрин при клике на другом мониторе.

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что это поведение сильно зависит от версии флеша и драйверов видеокарты. А вот от дистрибутива - практически не зависит.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно использовать последние версии ОС. Если Ubuntu, то лучше LTS версии. Ubuntu 14.04 я использую, мне нравиться.

Answer (score 0):

Из всег де лучше всего с мониторами работают кеды(kde) и крыса (xfce). В обеих ДЕ настроить мониторы проблем никаких не составит все интуитивно понятно. Если у вас две видюхи, то может быть проблема, что каждый моник берет себе отдельную видяху, но это я уже не знаю как лечить. 
И если у тебя 16 бубунта, то такая поблема объясняется тем что 16 гг. Минт тоже недавно обновился так что прискачке выбирай 17.3 минт (крыса или кеды).